# iOS Mail auto corrects after mail is sent

Tags: ios, mail.app, autocorrect

This is a common annoyance. I send an email to myself while away from my desk for something that I can follow up on later at my desk. I put something short in the subject. Because this has happened many times, I am very careful to see that the letters typed into the subject are exactly what I want.

Very often when I get the email, I find that the subject has been autocorrected into something incomprehensible. Today I got such an email with the subject being two pipe symbols (vertical bars).

In Mail in macOS you can change the spell correction to "as I type" instead of "when I click send". This would solve my problem, but there seems to be no such setting in iOS.

Any ideas?